# Prop drilling a function

Tags: reactjs

## I want to call the function onChangeStep() which lives in App.js from the third component down

What's the better way of doing this ?
Right now I'm trying to drill it all the way down using props and it's still now working.

## App.js --> Comp2 --> Comp3 -> onChangeStep

## Main Component

```
  import React, { Component } from "react";

    export default class App extends Component {
      state = {
        var: ""
      };

      onChangeStep() {
        this.setState({ var: "changed" });
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Comp2 onChangeStep={this.onChangeStep.bind(this)} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

## Comp2

```
    <Comp3
      onChangeStep={this.props.onChangeStep}
    />
```

## Comp3

```
import React from "react";

function handleClick(e, props) {
  this.props.onChangeStep();

}

const Comp3 = props => {
  return (
    <div className="column">
      <img
        onClick={e => handleClick(e, "src")}
        alt=""
        src="/cars"
        className="ui image"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Comp3;
```

Comment: Context or Redux can simplify it a bit

Comment: Strictly depends on your project's architecture and components missions, reusability requirements, etc. There can't be any exact answers...

Comment: @Valerii passing function through Redux tastes bad...

Comment: @Jay, not a function. You can dispatch action from Comp3 to change value and map this value to props in App. In your case it will be property changed or something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your Comp3 is a function, the "props" object is only available inside the scope of the const Comp3. 
A quick fix would be to turn Comp3 into a class component, like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Comp3 extends Component {

  handleClick = (e, props) => {
    this.props.onChangeStep();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="column">

      <img
        onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, "src")}
        alt=""
        src=""
        className="ui image"
      />
    </div>
    );
  }
}


export default Comp3;
```

To avoiding passing props through a long chain of components you should read about React.Context

Comment: in a class component, your props will be preceded by "this".

console.log(props) --> undefined
console.log(this.props) ---> onChangeStep

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so bad and is commonplace in a lot of React code bases. I will agree, though, that's it's not exactly perfect, though.

Other than what you're doing, the only other method I can think of at the moment is using a context.

```
const OnChangeStepContext = React.createContext(undefined)

class Parent extends React.Component {
    onChangeStep() {
        ...
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <OnChangeStepContext.Provider value={this.onChangeStep.bind(this)}>
                ...
            </OnChangeStepContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

function ChildOne() {
    ...
}

function ChildTwo() {
    const onChangeStep = useContext(OnChangeStepContext)

    return (
        <img onClick{onChangeStep} ... />
    )
}
```