# Is there any way to connect two dragable cards with a dynamic line segment (with symbols at end points) in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, deployment, frontend

[image: React rnd dragable component]

I want a dynamic line segment to connect two react rnd components. The line segment end points should be symbols. Also whenever I move these components the line segment should move with them and if in case a 3rd component comes in between the line segment, the segment should choose some route by having turns/curves avoiding the 3rd or any other card.

Is it possible to create such thing in reactJS?

Comment: Certainly. You could look into the [SVG `<line/>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/line).

Comment: @motto, yes but it is static. It doesn't changes continuously with the drag and it cuts other cards in between

Comment: My friend, you may set the props of an svg line element in the way that you can set the props of any other element in react.

Comment: @motto, thanks. I realised this that the props can be set in such a way that the position will change on drag event simultaneously.

Comment: @motto, but the issue that whenever another cards come in between the two connecting cards, the line should take turns to avoid them is still an issue. Dunno how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

From a comment (but not in the original question):

> whenever another cards come in between the two connecting cards, the line should take turns to avoid them

There are many options, some of them messier than others, but all of them are essentially "render the lines into an SVG element which is higher up the element tree than all the boxes".

The "simplest" (but not "most straightforward") approach would be to have a grandparent component that contains all your boxes and is responsible for rendering the lines into the SVG. It might provide callbacks to `addLine()` / `moveLine()` / `removeLine()` which get passed down the element hierarchy, and each pair of boxes is responsible for calling those as appropriate:

```js
function LineContainer() {
    const addLine    = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => { /* some magic */ return id; }
    const removeLine = (id) => { /* remove line */ };
    /* ... */
    return (<>
      <svg>
        { lines.map(([x1,y1,x2,y2]) => <line x1={x1} y1={y1} ... /> }
      </svg>

      <WhateverRendersTheBoxes addLine={addLine} removeLine={removeLine} />
    </>)
}

function BoxPair({ addLine, removeLine }) {
    /* ... */

    useEffect(() => {
        const id = addLine({ x1, y1, x2, y2 });
        return removeLine(id);
    }, [x1, y1, x2, y2]);

    return <>
      <Box x={x1} y={y1} />
      <Box x={x2} y={y2} />
    </>
}
```

Of course, your component hierarchy for rendering the boxes might be pretty messy, and [prop-drilling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57564842/21146235) isn't a lot of fun, so maybe it would be better as a [Context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context):

```js
const LineContext = createContext();

function LineContainer() {
    /* ... same as above ... */
    return (<>
      <svg>
        { lines.map(([x1,y1,x2,y2]) => <line x1={x1} y1={y1} ... /> }
      </svg>

      <LineContext.Provider value={{ addLine, removeLine }}>
        <WhateverRendersTheBoxes />
      </LineContext.Provider>
    </>)
}

function BoxPair() {
    const { addLine, removeLine } = useContext(LineContext);
    /* ... same as above ... */
}
```

I would recommend a different approach which keeps the responsibility (and logic) for line drawing *within the `BoxPair` component*, while rendering the `<line>` wherever it needs to be in the element hierarchy for your z-index stacking to work.

To do this, you can use a [portal](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal). Portals simply render part of your component tree somewhere else in the element hierarchy, outside the current component. You could create your SVG element as before, and each `BoxPair` can render its connecting line higher up the element tree:

```js
function LineContainer() {
    const [lineContainer, setLineContainer = useState();
    return (<>
      <svg ref={setLineContainer} />

      <WhateverRendersTheBoxes lineContainer={lineContainer} />
    </>);
}

function BoxPair({ lineContainer }) {
    /* ... */

    return <>
      <Box x={x1} y={y1} />
      <Box x={x2} y={y2} />

      { lineContainer &&
        createPortal(
          <line x1={pos1.x} y1={pos1.y} ... />,
          lineContainer
        ) }
    </>
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-cookies-gsk81i?file=/src/App.tsx)

[image: Boxes are rendered on top of lines]

For simplicity here I'm passing the `lineContainer` element reference directly as a prop, but as before you could use a context:

```js
    <LineContainerContext.Provider value={lineContainer}>
      <WhateverRendersTheBoxes />
    </LineContainerContext.Provider>
...
    const lineContainer = useContext(LineContainerContext);
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-carlos-d1h2xm?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Thanks @motto, such a detailed answer. I will check into this and see what happens.

Comment: we could have used react flow library